# CircleCIでデプロイ自動化のとき”Error: Missing required flag”のエラーが発生します

Tags: docker, heroku, circleci

#### 環境

ruby 2.6.5
rails 6
MySQL
M1チップ搭載macOS

#### 解決したいこと

CircleCI起動時、"Error: Missing required flag"のエラーが発生し、Herokuに自動デプロイできません。
アプリが紐付いていないエラーだと思います。
githubのリポジトリ名とHerokuのアプリ名が違うのですが、これが原因でしょうか？
他にどういったことが考えられますか？

教えていただきたいです！

#### 発生している問題・エラー

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

#### 該当するソースコード

**config.yml**

```yaml
version: 2.1
orbs:
  ruby: circleci/ruby@1.1.2
  heroku: circleci/heroku@1.2.3

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.6.5-node
    working_directory: ~/fridge_app
    steps:
      - checkout:
          path: ~/fridge_app
      - ruby/install-deps
      - run:
            name: yarn Install
            command: yarn install

  test:
      docker:
        - image: circleci/ruby:2.6.5-node
        - image: circleci/mysql:5.5
          environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
            MYSQL_DATABASE: fridge_app_test
      environment:
        BUNDLE_JOBS: "3"
        BUNDLE_RETRY: "3"
        FRIDGE_APP_DATABASE_HOST: "127.0.0.1"
        RAILS_ENV: test
      working_directory: ~/fridge_app
      steps:
        - checkout:
            path: ~/fridge_app
        - ruby/install-deps
        - run:
            name: yarn Install
            command: yarn install
        - run:
            name: Database setup
            command: bundle exec rails db:migrate
        - run:
            name: test
            command: bundle exec rspec
  deploy:
        docker:
          - image: circleci/ruby:2.6.5-node
        steps:
          - checkout
          - setup_remote_docker:
              version: 19.03.13
          - heroku/install
          - run:
              name: heroku login
              command: heroku container:login
          - run:
              name: push docker image
              command: heroku container:push web -a $HEROKU_APP_NAME
          - run:
              name: release docker image
              command: heroku container:release web -a $HEROKU_APP_NAME
          - run:
              name: datebase setup
              command: heroku run bundle exec rails db:migrate

workflows:
  version: 2
  build_test_and_deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test:
          requires:
            - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - test
          filters:
            branches:
              only: master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`heroku run` を、どの heroku app に対して実行するのか、が指定されていないがために発生しています。他の `heroku` コマンドと同じように、`-a $HEROKU_APP_NAME` を付与すれば解消すると思いますので、

```
heroku run -a $HEROKU_APP_NAME bundle exec rails db:migrate
```

でいけると思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます
無事デプロイの自動化できました！